# Corona widget.newButton passing data to function

Tags: lua, widget, coronasdk

I have scoured the documentation and google for a solution but none was found.

Simply: I want to pass data to a function, when a button is pressed.
Issue: The buttons are dynamically created, so the data must be presented when the button is built.

The code looks like this;

```
    myButton = widget.newButton({
        x = width * 0.875,
        y = height * heightChange,
        width = width * 0.18,
        height = height * 0.09,
        defaultFile = "Assets/Images/button_up.png",
        overFile = "Assets/Images/button_down.png",
        onEvent = func_myFunction
    })
```

But I want to do something like;

```
    onEvent = func_myFunction("My Data")
```

or

```
    onEvent = func_myFunction, myData
```

neither of which work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple you just need to add an eventlistener to the end of your code so when it's clicked your data would execute.

```
myButton = widget.newButton({
    x = width * 0.875,
    y = height * heightChange,
    width = width * 0.18,
    height = height * 0.09,
    defaultFile = "Assets/Images/button_up.png",
    overFile = "Assets/Images/button_down.png",
    onEvent = func_myFunction
})
myButton:addEventListener("touch",onEvent);
```

I hope this fixes your problem.